# [Swiper Carousel]Problems on setting up image size shown

Tags: html, css, carousel, swiper.js

Sorry to bother you guys, I used the swiper carousel demo in my project but I tried already an hour and still cannot get the whole picture to be shown in the slide. I used the demo "Autoplay".
I know the ratio may not totally fit into the slide, that's why i set the slide background to be half transparent(can see the background image), but that implies other minor problem.

Here is a little bit changed html code by me,

```
      <section id="sd">
       <!-- Swiper -->
       <div class="swiper mySwiper">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper">
           <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="../tenkait.png" alt="抱歉,你想找的商品已下架">
           </div>-->
           
           <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="../fatbuu.jpg" alt="抱歉,你想找的商品已下架">
           </div>
           
           <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="../proudprince.png" alt="抱歉,你想找的商品已下架">
           </div>
           
           <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="../onepiluffy.png" alt="抱歉,你想找的商品已下架">
           </div>
           
           <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="../slamdu.jpg" alt="抱歉,你想找的商品已下架">
           </div>
           
           <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="../cybform.png" alt="抱歉,你想找的商品已下架">
           </div>
           
         </div>
         <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
       </div>
    </section>
```

And below are the css part changed,

```
#sd .swiper mySwiper{
position: relative;
height: 500px;
background: #eee;
font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #000;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#sd .swiper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#sd .swiper-slide {
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
background: #fff;
opacity: 0.5;
display: flex;
height: 500px;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

#sd .swiper-slide:hover{
opacity: 1.0;
}

#sd .swiper-slide img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
/* height: auto; */
object-fit: cover;
opacity: 1.0;
z-index: 2;
}

#sd .swiper-pagination-bullet {
width: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-width,var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size,15px));
height: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-height,var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size,15px));
background: #fff;
box-shadow:1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

[image no.1,image to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7hMJ.jpg)
For example i want to put this image(image no.1) into the slide, it is in 1440x1791,
but it comes up like this(result comeout)...
[result comeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1S4z.png)

It just took the whole slide 1472x500 to show part of the image, the "object-fit:cover" seems do not have any effect.
May anyone can help me to solve the issue? Thanks again

Already tried to edit the parameters in .swiper-slide and .swiper-slide img,
as they are the main properties which change the image behaviour.

```
display: flex;
height: 500px;
object-fit: cover;
```

Like these, tried use %, px and rem but still cannot get a satisfy effect